# video cannot be loaded on iOS websheet on iPhone 5c

Tags: ios, iphone, video, video-streaming, jwplayer

We are running a wifi network with captive portal and users need to watch video before they get wifi. The problem is that the video cannot play on iPhone websheet (the page that pops up when you connect to wifi signal). It shows the following error:

"The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported"

The video is mp4 format with H.264 codec. Framerate is 30. Encoder profile is baseline and level 1.3. More details as follows:

```
x264 Unparse: level=1.3:bframes=0:cabac=0:8x8dct=0:weightp=0:vbv-bufsize=2000:vbv-maxrate=768
```

We are using JWPlayer 5.10.

The iPhone that showed the error was iPhone 5c with iOS 8.4.1. The error only occurs on websheet. Video can play without any problem on Safari. Also video can play successfully on both websheet and Safari on iPhone 6.

Any idea and help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 5.10 is pretty old. Do you have any way you can send a link for people to be able to troubleshoot? Also We are on JW7 now. I would at the very least try 6, or 7, to see if the issue still happens ...

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer, you can use this link to see the video http://bit.ly/1NFDHsL

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer, this issue only occurred on iOS websheet.app on iPhone 5s/iPhone 5c. If you open it in browser, it will work fine.

Comment: Can't really debug in a websheet easily. I would suggest trying a recent version of our player. 5.10 was released over 3 years ago.